# Changing and adding named CSS color values

Tags: html, css

In CSS, I'm curious if it's possible to make some more named colors. CSS only has 140 of these, and I'm hope to add more. I checked a list of the named colors [here](http://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_names.asp) and I thought there wasn't enough, and I wanted to add #2956B2. I also wanted to add colors, or modify the ones that aren't what most people think of for each color (eg: pink is light pink, yellow is to intense).

I've tried defining variables, but using the var() tags is a confusing thing to remember as I would have to know which colors had var() tags and which ones did not. You can view what I'm trying to do on this fiddle.

Comment: *"... CSS only has 140 preset colors"*, actually, CSS implementation in most browsers enables them to identify 140 **named** colors. *"I'm intending to add a couple more"*, you can't. In order to add more names you need to get browser vendors add them to the list which is unlikely they do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use the standard HEX code or RGB format as there is no way to set a new named color. The preset colors are built into the browser itself.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Now I know what I'm doing is impossible... Thanks for the help, though :D